# Windows batch script to read an .ini file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ini

I'm trying to read an `.ini` file with the following format:

```
[SectionName]
total=4
[AnotherSectionName]
total=7
[OtherSectionName]
total=12
```

Basically I want to print out certain values from the `.ini` file, for example the total under `OtherSectionName` followed by the total from `AnotherSectionName`.

Answer (score 48):

Here's a command file (`ini.cmd`) you can use to extract the relevant values:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set file=%~1
set area=[%~2]
set key=%~3
set currarea=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("!file!") do (
    set ln=%%a
    if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
        set currarea=!ln!
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
            set currkey=%%b
            set currval=%%c
            if "x!area!"=="x!currarea!" if "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                echo !currval!
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

And here's a transcript showing it in action (I've manually indented the output to make it easier to read):

```
c:\src>type ini.ini
    [SectionName]
    total=4
    [AnotherSectionName]
    total=7
    [OtherSectionName]
    total=12
c:\src>ini.cmd ini.ini SectionName total
    4
c:\src>ini.cmd ini.ini AnotherSectionName total
    7
c:\src>ini.cmd ini.ini OtherSectionName total
    12
```

To actually use this in another `cmd` file, just replace the `echo %val%` line below with whatever you want to do with it):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call ini.cmd ini.ini AnotherSectionName total') do (
    set val=%%a
)
echo %val%
```

Comment: Interesting, but it requires no spaces, at least no spaces between variables and values. "total = 12" is not supported

Comment: @Kar.ma, nothing in the question seemed to indicate the need to handle spaces so, if you *have* that need, another question might be warranted. I'd ask the OP whether they actually wanted to do that but, since they haven't been seen since 2012, I'm not confident of a response :-)

Comment: what is x used for before the delayed expansions? For example `x!currarea!`?

Comment: @voger, it prevents errors in the case where the variable is set to empty string.

Answer (score 26):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I decided to write a general purpose ini file utility batch script to address this question.

The script will let you retrieve or modify values in an ini-style file. Its searches are case-insensitive, and it preserves blank lines in the ini file. In essence, it allows you to interact with an ini file as a sort of very rudimentary database.

This script will work fine if you're reading / writing only alphanumeric values or symbols that have no special meaning to the `cmd` interpreter.  If you need something capable of handling values containing ampersands, percents, etc, see the **Update** section below.

```
:: --------------------
:: ini.bat
:: ini.bat /? for usage
:: --------------------

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

goto begin

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 /i item [/v value] [/s section] inifile
echo;
echo Take the following ini file for example:
echo;
echo    [Config]
echo    password=1234
echo    usertries=0
echo    allowterminate=0
echo;
echo To read the "password" value:
echo    %~nx0 /s Config /i password inifile
echo;
echo To change the "usertries" value to 5:
echo    %~nx0 /s Config /i usertries /v 5 inifile
echo;
echo In the above examples, "/s Config" is optional, but will allow the selection of
echo a specific item where the ini file contains similar items in multiple sections.
goto :EOF

:begin
if "%~1"=="" goto usage
for %%I in (item value section found) do set %%I=
for %%I in (%*) do (
    if defined next (
        if !next!==/i set item=%%I
        if !next!==/v set value=%%I
        if !next!==/s set section=%%I
        set next=
    ) else (
        for %%x in (/i /v /s) do if "%%~I"=="%%x" set "next=%%~I"
        if not defined next (
            set "arg=%%~I"
            if "!arg:~0,1!"=="/" (
                1>&2 echo Error: Unrecognized option "%%~I"
                1>&2 echo;
                1>&2 call :usage
                exit /b 1
            ) else set "inifile=%%~I"
        )
    )
)
for %%I in (item inifile) do if not defined %%I goto usage
if not exist "%inifile%" (
    1>&2 echo Error: %inifile% not found.
    exit /b 1
)

if not defined section (
    if not defined value (
        for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (`findstr /i "^%item%\=" "%inifile%"`) do (
            echo(%%I
        )
    ) else (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`findstr /n "^" "%inifile%"`) do (
            set "line=%%I" && set "line=!line:*:=!"
            echo(!line! | findstr /i "^%item%\=" >NUL && (
                1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(%item%=%value%
                echo(%value%
            ) || 1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(!line!
        )
    )
) else (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`findstr /n "^" "%inifile%"`) do (
        set "line=%%I" && set "line=!line:*:=!"
        if defined found (
            if defined value (
                echo(!line! | findstr /i "^%item%\=" >NUL && (
                    1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(%item%=%value%
                    echo(%value%
                    set found=
                ) || 1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(!line!
            ) else echo(!line! | findstr /i "^%item%\=" >NUL && (
                for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in ("!line!") do (
                    echo(%%x
                    exit /b 0
                )
            )
        ) else (
            if defined value (1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(!line!)
            echo(!line! | find /i "[%section%]" >NUL && set found=1
        )
    )
)

if exist "%inifile%.1" move /y "%inifile%.1" "%inifile%">NUL
```

**Example**

Contents of `example.ini`:

```
[SectionName]
; This is a comment.
total=4

[AnotherSectionName]
# This is another comment.
total=7

[OtherSectionName]
And it should work with non-standard comments as well.
total=12
```

Test session:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>ini /s AnotherSectionName /i total example.ini
7

C:\Users\me\Desktop>ini /s othersectionname /i Total /v f00 example.ini
f00

C:\Users\me\Desktop>type example.ini
[SectionName]
; This is a comment.
total=4

[AnotherSectionName]
# This is another comment.
total=7

[OtherSectionName]
And it should work with non-standard comments as well.
Total=f00
```

---

#### Update

Apparently the [pure batch solution chokes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16015164/1683264) when it encounters characters like `&` (and probably `%` and others).  So here's a more robust batch + JScript hybrid script that addresses that problem.  The syntax and output are the same (but with an added `/d` switch to delete `item=value` pairs).

This script sets `%ERRORLEVEL%=0` for success, and `%ERRORLEVEL%=1` on error.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /* -- batch / JScript hybrid line to begin JScript comment

:: --------------------
:: ini.bat
:: ini.bat /? for usage
:: --------------------

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

goto begin

:: color code by jeb -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/1683264
:c
set "param=^%~2" !
set "param=!param:"=\"!"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\X" nul
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
exit /b
:: but it doesn't handle slashes.  :(
:s
<NUL set /p "=/"&exit /b

:usage
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%a"
<nul > X set /p ".=."

echo Usage:
call :c 07 "   query:"
call :c 0F " %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "i item ["&call :s&call :c 0F "s section] inifile"&echo;
call :c 07 "   create or modify:"
call :c 0F " %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "i item "&call :s&call :c 0F "v value ["&call :s&call :c 0F "s section] inifile"&echo;
call :c 07 "   delete:"
call :c 0F " %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "d item ["&call :s&call :c 0F "s section] inifile"&echo;
echo;
echo Take the following ini file for example:
echo;
echo    [Config]
echo    password=1234
echo    usertries=0
echo    allowterminate=0
echo;
echo To read the "password" value:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "i password inifile"&echo;
echo;
echo To modify the "usertries" value to 5:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "i usertries "&call :s&call :c 0F "v 5 inifile"&echo;
echo;
echo To add a "timestamp" key with a value of the current date and time:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "i timestamp "&call :s&call :c 0F "v ""%DEL%%%%%date%%%% %%%%time%%%%""%DEL% inifile"&echo;
echo;
echo To delete the "allowterminate" key:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "d allowterminate inifile"&echo;
echo;
call :c 07 "In the above examples, "&call :s
call :c 0F "s Config "
echo is optional, but will allow the selection of
echo a specific item where the ini file contains similar items in multiple sections.
del X
goto :EOF

:begin
if "%~1"=="" goto usage
for %%I in (item value section found) do set %%I=
for %%I in (%*) do (
    if defined next (
        if !next!==/i set "item=%%~I"
        if !next!==/v (
            set modify=true
            set "value=%%~I"
        )
        if !next!==/d (
            set "item=%%~I"
            set modify=true
            set delete=true
        )
        if !next!==/s set "section=%%~I"
        set next=
    ) else (
        for %%x in (/i /v /s /d) do if "%%~I"=="%%x" set "next=%%~I"
        if not defined next (
            set "arg=%%~I"
            if "!arg:~0,1!"=="/" (
                1>&2 echo Error: Unrecognized option "%%~I"
                1>&2 echo;
                1>&2 call :usage
                exit /b 1
            ) else set "inifile=%%~I"
        )
    )
)
for %%I in (item inifile) do if not defined %%I goto usage
if not exist "%inifile%" (
    1>&2 echo Error: %inifile% not found.
    exit /b 1
)

cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%inifile%" "!section!" "!item!" "!value!" "%modify%" "%delete%"

exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:: Begin JScript portion */
var inifile = WSH.Arguments(0),
section = WSH.Arguments(1),
item = WSH.Arguments(2),
value = WSH.Arguments(3),
modify = WSH.Arguments(4),
del = WSH.Arguments(5),
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
stream = fso.OpenTextFile(inifile, 1),

// (stream.ReadAll() will not preserve blank lines.)
data = [];
while (!stream.atEndOfStream) { data.push(stream.ReadLine()); }
stream.Close();

// trims whitespace from edges
String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'') }

// trim + toLowerCase
String.prototype.unify = function() { return this.trim().toLowerCase(); };

// unquotes each side of "var"="value"
String.prototype.splitEx = function(x) {
    for (var i=0, ret = this.split(x) || []; i<ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = ret[i].replace(/^['"](.*)['"]$/, function(m,$1){return $1});
    };
    return ret;
}

// splices a new element into an array just after the last non-empty element.  If first arg is a number, start at that position and look backwards.
Array.prototype.cram = function() {
    for (var args=[], i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) { args.push(arguments[i]); }
    var i = (typeof args[0] == "number" && Math.floor(args[0]) == args[0]) ? args.shift() : this.length;
    while (i>0 && !this[--i].length) {};
    for (var j=0; j<args.length; j++) this.splice(++i, 0, args[j]);
}

function saveAndQuit() {
    while (data && !data[data.length - 1].length) data.pop();
    var stream = fso.OpenTextFile(inifile, 2, true);
    stream.Write(data.join('\r\n') + '\r\n');
    stream.Close();
    WSH.Quit(0);
}

function fatal(err) {
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine(err);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

if (section && !/^\[.+\]$/.test(section)) section = '[' + section + ']';

if (modify) {
    if (section) {
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].unify() == section.unify()) {
                for (var j=i + 1; j<data.length; j++) {
                    if (/^\s*\[.+\]\s*$/.test(data[j])) break;
                    var keyval = data[j].splitEx('=');
                    if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
                    var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
                    if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
                        if (del) data.splice(j, 1);
                        else {
                            data[j] = item + '=' + value;
                            WSH.Echo(value.trim());
                        }
                        saveAndQuit();
                    }
                }
                if (del) fatal(item + ' not found in ' + section + ' in ' + inifile);
                data.cram(j ,item + '=' + value);
                WSH.Echo(value.trim());
                saveAndQuit();
            }
        }
        if (del) fatal(section + ' not found in ' + inifile);
        data.cram('\r\n' + section, item + '=' + value);
        WSH.Echo(value.trim());
        saveAndQuit();
    }
    else { // if (!section)
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var keyval = data[i].splitEx('=');
            if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
            var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
            if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
                if (del) data.splice(i, 1);
                else {
                    data[i] = item + '=' + value;
                    WSH.Echo(value.trim());
                }
                saveAndQuit();
            }
        }
        if (del) fatal(item + ' not found in ' + inifile);
        data.cram(item + '=' + value);
        WSH.Echo(value.trim());
        saveAndQuit();
    }
}
else if (section) { // and if (!modify)
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].unify() == section.unify()) {
            for (var j=i + 1; j<data.length; j++) {
                if (/^\s*\[.+\]\s*$/.test(data[j])) fatal(item + ' not found in ' + section + ' in ' + inifile);
                var keyval = data[j].splitEx('=');
                if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
                var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
                if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
                    WSH.Echo(val.trim());
                    WSH.Quit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fatal(section + ' not found in ' + inifile);
}
else { // if (item) and nothing else
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var keyval = data[i].splitEx('=');
        if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
        var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
        if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
            WSH.Echo(val.trim());
            WSH.Quit(0);
        }
    }
    fatal(item + ' not found in ' + inifile);
}
```

[image: ini.bat usage screen]

Comment: Excellent work! I have a Pull Request, though.  Add tildes to lines 37, 38, and 39 of the non-update version to strip quotes from the args. Ex. `if !next!==/i set item=%%~I`

Comment: Thanks for this! This post saved me a lot of time!

Comment: i need to parse the ini file, to get the sections names into variables... after that i want to interact with the user. offer them the distinct values and then use the selected one in the provided script... it's posible ? i'm not a batch coder

Comment: The first version will not work if the path to the ini file is absolute somewhere inside `Program Files (x86)`. It will be confused by the brackets.

Answer (score 16):

I have short proposition for read config.ini file in current directory form windows batch (.bat):

Near end of batch file we paste that code:

```
:ini    
@for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('find "%~2=" "%~1"') do @set %~3=%%a    
@goto:eof
```

And near start of batch file we call it by:

```
@call:ini "config.ini" IniFieldName batchVarName
@echo IniFieldName is: %batchVarName%
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Simple, short and reading setting key => value in a file that can just be edited with a DoubleClick.

Answer (score 9):

config.ini

```
foo=string
bar=123
baz=spaces work too!
```

---

windows_batch.cmd

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (config.ini) do set %%I
```

Comment: But wont work with Quotes (for example `foo="C:/Program Files/Test/"`)

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I just recently needed that and found @paxdiablo answer.
I needed something more so I enriched his answer and I'm now giving back.

What I also needed was finding which key held a specific value.
Also, explicitly support root section (no section name).

Here's my code, a function I put into a library (CMDLib variable) I call when I need it (among other functions).

```
:ReadINI
REM ReadINI - Get value from [Section]; Key from an INI File.
REM Arguments:
REM   File    INI-file to read from
REM   Key     Name of the entry
REM   Section Name of the [Section] under which the Value is.
REM     Optional, will find a value from the root section if empty.
REM               For root section, set to "-" to also use "Value"
REM   Value   If Key is set to "-", will find which Key has "Value"
REM
REM Returns: A string of text will be echoed, ready for logging.
REM   An echo of the value.
REM
REM Call example:
REM   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Call "%CMDLib%" ReadINI "Inifile" Key Section') do ( set Value=%%a)
REM
REM Original: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2866328/151152
rem ------- Function header -------
    Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    :: Logging formatting
    if not defined nest (set /a nest=0) else set /a Nest=%nest%+1
    if %nest% GEQ 1 if not defined _tab (set _tab=    ) else for /l %%i in (0, %nest%,1) do set _tab=%_tab%    
rem ------- Function body -------
    set file=%~1
    set key=%~2
    set Section=[%~3]
    if "%Section%"=="-" set Section=
    set value=%~4
    set currSection=
    Set RC=0
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
        set ln=%%a
        if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
            set currSection=!ln!
        ) else (
            for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
                set currkey=%%b
                set currval=%%c
                if /i "x!Section!"=="x!currSection!" (
                    if /i "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                        echo !currval!
                        if %_D% GEQ 2 echo %_tab%[%0 - RC:%RC%]
                        exit /b %RC%
                    ) Else if "x!key!"=="x-" (
                        if /i "x!value!"=="x!currval!" (
                            echo !currkey!
                            if %_D% GEQ 2 echo %_tab%[%0 - RC:%RC%]
                            exit /b %RC%
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    if %_D% GEQ 2 echo %_tab%[%0 - RC:%RC%]
    Exit /b %RC%
rem ------- Function end -------
```

No syntax highlighting for CMD?  That's a shame.. ;-)

Hope this helps other as well.

Comment: ok, i know it's very old answer but i came across it and it seems to be the solution i need. 
the only problem  is that you use %_D% var and i can't find the initialization for it is seems to be empty.
can you please tell me what it's for?

Comment: I totally forgot to explain this. _D is a debug output variable only, used throughout scripts I write.  It was in the function because I had it already.  You can either set it at the top to visually validate the output or remove such lines, they have no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe this helps someone.. Had to build it since inifile.exe ran out of tricks and seems every damn ini parser on web needs 'KEY' when all I need is all values under [section]. So, here's section print..

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
IF "%1"=="" (echo Usage: section input.ext output.ext & goto eof )
IF "%2"=="" (echo Usage: section input.ext output.ext & goto eof )
IF NOT EXIST "%2" (echo File does not exist. Usage: section input.ext output.ext & goto eof )
IF "%3"=="" (echo Usage: section input.ext output.ext & goto eof )
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('findstr /I /N "\[.*\]" %2') DO (echo %%A>>LINE_START.DAT)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A IN ('findstr /I "\[%1\]" LINE_START.DAT') DO (
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set FIRSTLINE=%%A
)
set /a "FIRSTLINE+=1"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A IN ('findstr /I /N ".*" %2') DO (
IF %%A GEQ !FIRSTLINE! (echo %%B>>LINE_END.DAT)
)
set ENDLINE=500
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A IN ('findstr /I /N "\[.*\]" LINE_END.DAT') DO (
IF %%A LSS !ENDLINE! (set /a "ENDLINE=%%A") ELSE echo %%A>nul
)
set /a "ENDLINE-=1"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A IN ('findstr /I /N ".*" LINE_END.DAT') DO (
IF %%A LEQ !ENDLINE! (echo %%B>>%3) ELSE ENDLOCAL
)
set ENDLINE=0
set FIRSTLINE=0
ENDLOCAL
DEL /Q LINE_*.DAT
:end
```

Yeah, yeah I know it looks like it's from rear, but it works, although, not sure will it work with spaces in folder or spaces in files. Built it to basically just have .ini file at same folder and ran from command-line.

Usage: genetix_ini.cmd section input.ext output.ext

UPDATE #2:
Seems, I made mistake on not zeroing the 2 set vars. Which started to cause an issue at second pass of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for this *excellent* INI script and the update published on May 23, 2017. Still very useful!

I did **add a /q** switch, **to "be quiet"**, thus suppressing messages issued by the fatal() function.
This was necessary since I'm calling the INI script from a Windows CMD script, where I found out that redirection of stdout (1>) and stderr (2>) don't intercept messages issued by the windows scripting host.

An example:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ini /s Section /i Entry File.ini`) do set go_drive=%%a 1> nul: 2> nul:
```

...doesn't suppress error messages, while...

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ini /q /s Section /i Entry File.ini`) do set go_drive=%%a 1> nul: 2> nul:
```

...is suppressing the error messages

I've posted the code adjacent to this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /* -- batch / JScript hybrid line to begin JScript comment

:: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: ini.bat
:: ini.bat /? for usage
::
:: Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866117/windows-batch-script-to-read-an-ini-file
::
:: 2021-08-03: /q switch added, to suppress error messages
:: 
:: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

goto begin

:: color code by jeb -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/1683264
:c
set "param=^%~2" !
set "param=!param:"=\"!"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\X" nul
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
exit /b
:: but it doesn't handle slashes.  :(
:s
<NUL set /p "=/"&exit /b

:usage
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%a"
<nul > X set /p ".=."

echo Usage:
call :c 07 "   query:"
call :c 0F " %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "i item ["&call :s&call :c 0F "s section] inifile"&echo;
call :c 07 "   create or modify:"
call :c 0F " %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "i item "&call :s&call :c 0F "v value ["&call :s&call :c 0F "s section] inifile"&echo;
call :c 07 "   delete:"
call :c 0F " %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "d item ["&call :s&call :c 0F "s section] inifile"&echo;
call :c 07 "   quiet:"
call :c 0F " %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "q "&echo;
echo;
echo Take the following ini file for example:
echo;
echo    [Config]
echo    password=1234
echo    usertries=0
echo    allowterminate=0
echo;
echo To read the "password" value:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "i password inifile"&echo;
echo;
echo To modify the "usertries" value to 5:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "i usertries "&call :s&call :c 0F "v 5 inifile"&echo;
echo;
echo To add a "timestamp" key with a value of the current date and time:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "i timestamp "&call :s&call :c 0F "v ""%DEL%%%%%date%%%% %%%%time%%%%""%DEL% inifile"&echo;
echo;
echo To delete the "allowterminate" key:
call :c 0F "   %~nx0 "&call :s&call :c 0F "s Config "&call :s&call :c 0F "d allowterminate inifile"&echo;
echo;
call :c 07 "In the above examples, "&call :s
call :c 0F "s Config "
echo is optional, but will allow the selection of
echo a specific item where the ini file contains similar items in multiple sections.
del X
goto :EOF

:begin
if "%~1"=="" goto usage
for %%I in (item value section found) do set %%I=
for %%I in (%*) do (
    if defined next (
        if !next!==/i set "item=%%~I"
        if !next!==/v (
            set modify=true
            set "value=%%~I"
        )
        if !next!==/d (
            set "item=%%~I"
            set modify=true
            set delete=true
        )
        if !next!==/s set "section=%%~I"
:
:   /q switch added. Suppress error messages.
:
        if !next!==/q set quiet=true
        set next=
    ) else (
        for %%x in (/i /v /s /d /q) do if "%%~I"=="%%x" set "next=%%~I"
        if not defined next (
            set "arg=%%~I"
            if "!arg:~0,1!"=="/" (
                1>&2 echo Error: Unrecognized option "%%~I"
                1>&2 echo;
                1>&2 call :usage
                exit /b 1
            ) else set "inifile=%%~I"
        )
    )
)
for %%I in (item inifile) do if not defined %%I goto usage
if not exist "%inifile%" (
    1>&2 echo Error: %inifile% not found.
    exit /b 1
)

cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%inifile%" "!section!" "!item!" "!value!" "%modify%" "%delete%" "%quiet%"

exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:: Begin JScript portion */
var inifile = WSH.Arguments(0),
section = WSH.Arguments(1),
item = WSH.Arguments(2),
value = WSH.Arguments(3),
modify = WSH.Arguments(4),
del = WSH.Arguments(5),
quiet = WSH.Arguments(6),
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
stream = fso.OpenTextFile(inifile, 1),

// (stream.ReadAll() will not preserve blank lines.)
data = [];
while (!stream.atEndOfStream) { data.push(stream.ReadLine()); }
stream.Close();

// trims whitespace from edges
String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'') }

// trim + toLowerCase
String.prototype.unify = function() { return this.trim().toLowerCase(); };

// unquotes each side of "var"="value"
String.prototype.splitEx = function(x) {
    for (var i=0, ret = this.split(x) || []; i<ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = ret[i].replace(/^['"](.*)['"]$/, function(m,$1){return $1});
    };
    return ret;
}

// splices a new element into an array just after the last non-empty element.  If first arg is a number, start at that position and look backwards.
Array.prototype.cram = function() {
    for (var args=[], i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) { args.push(arguments[i]); }
    var i = (typeof args[0] == "number" && Math.floor(args[0]) == args[0]) ? args.shift() : this.length;
    while (i>0 && !this[--i].length) {};
    for (var j=0; j<args.length; j++) this.splice(++i, 0, args[j]);
}

function saveAndQuit() {
    while (data && !data[data.length - 1].length) data.pop();
    var stream = fso.OpenTextFile(inifile, 2, true);
    stream.Write(data.join('\r\n') + '\r\n');
    stream.Close();
    WSH.Quit(0);
}

function fatal(err) {
    if (!quiet) {
        WSH.StdErr.WriteLine(err);
    }
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

if (section && !/^\[.+\]$/.test(section)) section = '[' + section + ']';

if (modify) {
    if (section) {
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].unify() == section.unify()) {
                for (var j=i + 1; j<data.length; j++) {
                    if (/^\s*\[.+\]\s*$/.test(data[j])) break;
                    var keyval = data[j].splitEx('=');
                    if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
                    var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
                    if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
                        if (del) data.splice(j, 1);
                        else {
                            data[j] = item + '=' + value;
                            WSH.Echo(value.trim());
                        }
                        saveAndQuit();
                    }
                }
                if (del) fatal(item + ' not found in ' + section + ' in ' + inifile);
                data.cram(j ,item + '=' + value);
                WSH.Echo(value.trim());
                saveAndQuit();
            }
        }
        if (del) fatal(section + ' not found in ' + inifile);
        data.cram('\r\n' + section, item + '=' + value);
        WSH.Echo(value.trim());
        saveAndQuit();
    }
    else { // if (!section)
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var keyval = data[i].splitEx('=');
            if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
            var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
            if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
                if (del) data.splice(i, 1);
                else {
                    data[i] = item + '=' + value;
                    WSH.Echo(value.trim());
                }
                saveAndQuit();
            }
        }
        if (del) fatal(item + ' not found in ' + inifile);
        data.cram(item + '=' + value);
        WSH.Echo(value.trim());
        saveAndQuit();
    }
}
else if (section) { // and if (!modify)
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].unify() == section.unify()) {
            for (var j=i + 1; j<data.length; j++) {
                if (/^\s*\[.+\]\s*$/.test(data[j])) fatal(item + ' not found in ' + section + ' in ' + inifile);
                var keyval = data[j].splitEx('=');
                if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
                var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
                if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
                    WSH.Echo(val.trim());
                    WSH.Quit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fatal(section + ' not found in ' + inifile);
}
else { // if (item) and nothing else
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var keyval = data[i].splitEx('=');
        if (keyval.length < 2) continue;
        var key = keyval.shift(), val = keyval.join('=');
        if (key.unify() == item.unify()) {
            WSH.Echo(val.trim());
            WSH.Quit(0);
        }
    }
    fatal(item + ' not found in ' + inifile);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might also get more robust operation by using a tool specific to ini files like https://github.com/pixelb/crudini