# Save and Load .bat game -- Error with single numbers

Tags: batch-file

In this qustion, [Save and Load .bat game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681299/save-and-load-bat-game) I used Mat's answer.

But now I have a problem with "saving" numbers using said answer.

If the variable is not double digits (for example 1 or 0) it will "save" the variable as " " and thus will crash the game whenever you do anything that needs that variable. The game sets the variable fine before that.

For example if I pick up the rag, then type Inv, it will say I'm holding the rag. If I then save and load again, then type Inv, it wont say I'm holding anything!

It also won't echo "Nothing" which it should do if `%raghave% = 00`

(I also have the save file open in Notepad++ and so can see that `set RagHave=`)

(Also if I use Mat's code with the spaces, then the variable is set as `"set RagHave=1`" and so adds a space at the end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Mat's solution!
For better understanding I repeat his solution

```
@echo @ECHO OFF           > savegame.cmd
@echo SET ITEMS=%ITEMS%   >> savegame.cmd
@echo SET HEALTH=%HEALTH% >> savegame.cmd
@echo SET MONEY=%MONEY%   >> savegame.cmd
```

In my opinion, it has multiple disadvantages.
The `@` prefix isn't necessaray.
The redirection is repeated for each line (I don't like redundancy).
It needs the spaces, as without spaces you got problems with numbers.

Sample with items=1

```
@echo set ITEMS=1>>savegame.cmd
```

This results not in writeing `set items=1` it writes `set items=` to `1>>savegame.cmd` 1>> is the standard stream.

You can solve all problems with

```
(
    echo @ECHO OFF
    echo SET "ITEMS=%ITEMS%"
    echo SET "HEALTH=%HEALTH%"
    echo SET "MONEY=%MONEY%"
) > savegame.cmd
```

The quotes are used to ensure that "hidden" spaces after the set are ignored.

Btw. It's a bad idea to use a construct like `if %raghave% = 00`, (you need two equal signs), as `00` isn't a normal number you can't count or calculate with it, it's better to use `0` instead.

Then also this should work

```
set /a items=0
set /a items=items+1
set /a items=items-1
if %items%==0 echo There are no items
```

Comment: I was using 00 only to test to see if Mat's way liked 00, which it did. Thanks for the help, this worked! I did wonder about the @. I also have it saving to .ParadoxSave, which I then have it rename to a .cmd, and back again when it loads (something which I quite liked)