# Batch File load ini file with comments

Tags: batch-file, comments, ini

I would like to use a batch script to automate some work that I will give customers.  I want to give them an INI file **WITH** comments (so they understand what they are setting).

Example INI:

```
[General]
;Set your operating system
OS=Windows7
```

[Read ini from windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866117/read-ini-from-windows-batch-file) Is a good start but does not help with comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what you want is the code listed in the answer in the link you provided to ignore the comments?

Comment: Check out this example at Rob van der Woude: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=readini_nt

Comment: @ itdoesntwork I thought it would be a good base, but not what I ultimately want.  Since I want the variable set to its value so I can use it.

Comment: @ZackM - I just added an [ini utility script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15413717/1683264) to the page you linked.  It will let you read and modify ini values, and is tolerant of comments.

Comment: [Reading an ini config file from a batch file « Almanac Hackers](http://almanachackers.com/blog/2009/12/31/reading-an-ini-config-file-from-a-batch-file/)

Answer (score 0):

The FOR statement has the EOL option that specifies a character that indicates the line is to be ignored if it appears in the 1st position on a line. The default EOL character is `;`, so you don't have to do anything special to ignore lines that begin with `;`.

Your requirements are not very clear. I'm not sure what (if anything) you want to do with the section labels like [General]. I'm going to ignore them.

You can use FIND or FINDSTR to filter out any line that does not contain `=`.

Here is a simple script that will load variables as defined by the .ini file. Lines that begin with `;` are comments. Section headers are ignored.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr = example.ini') do %%A
```

Comment: Section labels would be used for organization and would not be needed.  However, that does make another tag type other than comment.

Comment: Might break if the comment includes a `=`, not sure though

Comment: @itdoesntwork - no, the FOR statement will ignore all comment lines (lines beginning with `;`), regardless of content. But it could falsely load section labels that contain `=`. For exampe, `[this=is loaded]`. The FINDSTR could be tailored to prevent this.