# Batch file conditional copy after ini reading

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements, ini

In my PCs I have a series of files that are in the Path `C:\Meleena`

In some previous installations this path was different (it was `C:\second_path\Meleena`).

After fixing every computers to the path `C:\Meleena`  I  have 2 different scenarios:

- PC where I have only `C:\Meleena`
- PC where I have `C:\second_path\Meleena`

I might therefore have in `C:\Windows\Settings.ini` a situation like this:

```
[Summer]
Meleena=C:\Meleena
```

or

```
[Summer]
Meleena=C:\second_path\Meleena
```

I wonder if a batch file might read from `C:\Windows\Settings.ini` the `[Summer]` section and do the following:

- If `Meleena` = `C:\Meleena` do not do anything;
- If `Meleena` = `C:\second_path\Meleena`

Copy all files from `C:\Meleena` to `C:\second_path\Meleena`

Is there a possibility to get a batch file to read this section from `Settings.ini` and do a conditional copy?

Many thanks to all of you.

Meleena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with parameters: C:>ini.bat settings.ini Summer Meleena C:\Meleena

ini.bat:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set file=%~1
set area=[%~2]
set key=%~3
set val=%~4
set currarea=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("!file!") do (
    set ln=%%a
    if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
        set currarea=!ln!
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
            set currkey=%%b
            set currval=%%c
            if "x!area!"=="x!currarea!" if "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                if not "x!val!"=="x!currval!" (
                    echo !currval!
                    xcopy !val! !currval! /H /E /G /Q /R /Y
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

[Read ini from windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866117/read-ini-from-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
for /f "skip=2" %%a in ('find /v "[Summer]" C:\Windows\Settings.ini') do (
if "%%a"=="C:\second_path\Meleena" (
xcopy C:\Meleena C:\second_path\Meleena
)
)
```