# Read settings from a .conf

Tags: batch-file

I need a way to load my own custom settings from an .conf file eg. in .conf

```
Color=45
title=Hello World
default-text=hello
echo-at-start=Welcome
```

Comment: Which language and what did you try?

Comment: It's batch, as indicated by the [batch-file] tag.

Comment: look under the question please! and I have tried using `<<`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read ini from windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866117/read-ini-from-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes your file is called settings.conf, and that it's in the same directory as the batch script.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in (settings.conf) do set "%%A"
```

Comment: Environment variable color=45 not defined

Comment: It didnt show that this time :/, but it doesnt do any of the settings

Comment: It shows all of them for me. http://i.imgur.com/kEpaNFS.png How are you calling the for loop?

Comment: Just copied `@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in (settings.conf) do set %%A` into batch and `color=20
title=ds` in the settings.conf

Comment: I'm assuming this is part of a larger script. Are the variables getting replaced somewhere else in the code?

Comment: It is supposed to load the settings not view them

Comment: I'm just echoing them to show that the variable loading worked. The code above doesn't echo anything, and so you won't get a message or anything if it worked.

Comment: Yes it is, https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2bqlhvahx8ur8w/SD-Security.bat?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/omwdf88ns63js5e/SD-Security.exe?dl=0