# How to edit and read specific lines of a text document with a Batch script

Tags: batch-file, text, edit

I am writing a Batch text adventure at the moment, and I am attempting to find a way to make a world save and also save the various bits of armor and the statistics they have onto a text document. I am at a loss for how to do this, and I was wondering if anyone could help.

By the way, I mean the actual Batch Scripting Language, on it's own. I do not mean things like PowerShell or VBScript, although, if this Batch turns out to not be worth it, I might switch to it for continued development.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is way too braod here! Include your efforts by editing your question and describe precisely where you are stuck; otherwise your question is likely going to be closed as off-topic...

Comment: You could use [ini.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15413717/1683264).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you have the script setup.  If you are having the info set as variables like %armor% or w.e you can use set out.  Here is an example,

```
@Echo Off
set /p armor=
Set "out=C:\users\*your login name*\Desktop"
 >  "%out%\YourFileName.txt"(
echo %armor%
)
```

Then whatever the armor variable is set it will be put in the text document. Not sure if this is sufficent as I am fairly new to messing with scripts myself but hope it helps!